# How to implement a scalable notification system for social application?

Tags: mysql, notifications, social-networking

I'm working on a notification system for yet another social type application. It has posts, comments, and several other features etc, and my current implementation goes like this,

I have different notification tables for each object (6 tables in total) (post_notif, comment_notif etc)
Each table stores the notif_id, to_user, from_user, type (like, favourite etc), object_id, ..., created_at etc.

Each table has more than 4 indexes because there are several foreign keys that will be joined in the query (min 4 JOINS per query).

All 6 tables are queried with union all,
eg

```
SELECT col_a, col_b..
    UNION ALL
SELECT col_a, col_b..
    UNION ALL..
...
```

I need the notifications to update with any changes to the objects that may get updated so it is reflected in the notifications the user sees (e.g. 'Johnny commented:"That's awesome!"', 'Johnny commented: "That's great.') which is the reasoning for separate tables for objects with foreign keys and union all in the notification retrieval.

I'm using MySql, Ids are generated from a ticket server, and I'm using NodeJs as the api front end if this helps.

**My question is**

This will in my opinion be extremely inefficient as the app scales and I'm looking to see if there is a better way or more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Please add the tables structure and some sample data. I do not know if any solution I can think of is applicable...

Comment: Its pretty simple, each notif table references the object it represents, the joins on notif tables are for usernames etc. It works, it just doesn't seem like its a long term solution, who knows...